# Is this play involving Red Eyes Darkness Metal Dragon & Lightpulsar Dragon valid?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

I was playing against a kid on dueling network and he swore that this play wasn't legal and I pretty much just ended the match to avoid arguing. I know I might be wrong, but here's how it went (basically OTK cause he had no Effect Veilers, Battle Faders & only 2 cards on backrow which he didn't activate):

In my hand I had 2 Galaxy Eyes Photon Dragons. On the field I had Red Eyes Darkness Metal Dragon (I'm going to write REDMD for short) & Lightpulsar Dragon.

I special summoned Galaxy Eyes Photon Dragon tributing REDMD & Lightpulsar. Since they technically should both go to grave together I special summoned REDMD using Lightpulsar's effect. 
 
I special summon Lightpulsar using REDMD effect. 
Special summon another Galaxy Eyes from hand, again special summon REDMD using Lightpulsar's eff, then special summon Lightpulsar. 
Overlay for Heiratic Overlord, detach one, tribute REDMD first (important) & then Lightpulsar to pop his backrow. Lightpulsar effect I special summon REDMD again, REDMD special summon Galaxy Eyes photon & attack for OTK.

Comment: Which part in particular was the other kid saying wasn't legal? Or just the sheer unfairness of it all?

Comment: being able to ss redmd when i tributed them to ss galaxy eyes pohton

Comment: He was right, Lightpulsar misses the timing in this example. See user4939's answer and my comment for details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [rulings page for Lightpulsar Dragon](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Card_Rulings%3aLightpulsar_Dragon#cite_note-5) says:

> If "Lightpulsar Dragon" and "Red-Eyes Darkness Metal Dragon" are
>   destroyed on the field simultaneously by the effect of "Dark Hole",
>   that "Red-Eyes Darkness Metal Dragon" can be Special Summoned from the
>   Graveyard by the effect of "Lightpulsar Dragon".[6]

And that is allegedly a ruling from an official Konami FAQ, though the link to it was broken.

If REDMD and Lightpulsar Dragon are fine to combo in this way then I don't really see the problem with your OTK.  It's not like Lightpulsar Dragon isn't known for featuring in lots of OTK decks... anyone can just google it to see that!

Comment: The problem is timing. Lightpulsar's effect is an optional Trigger effect featuring "When", so it can only be activated if **nothing happens after its triggering condition**. In this case, after it is sent to the graveyard (its triggering condition), a Monster is Special Summoned, so it will miss the timing. In the ruling, nothing happens after the destruction by Dark Hole, so missing the timing is not an issue. See also user4939's answer.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't work that way, due to the fact that Lightpulsar is being tributed his effect does not go off, and the same for Heliopolis. Lightpulsar must be "destroyed" or "sent" as the final resolution to an effect. When Dark Hole kills them both the last activation is Lightpulsar which is why he can summon D-Metal but in the instance listed above Lightpulsar misses timing in all 3 instances. It's just like why you can't use Lightpulsar to synchro with and get D-Metal back.

e.g. Dragunity Phalanx and Lightpulsar on field, synchro for scrap dragon, grab D-Metal, D-Metal grab Pulsar, scrap hit Pulsar and opponent's card, pulsar effect grab another D-Metal, summon Pulsar. 28,28,28,25. Konami issued a miss timing rule with Lightpulsar Dragon.

Comment: Technically, they didn't "issue a miss timing rule", it's just that Lightpulsar is an optional Trigger effect and those will miss the timing if something happens after their triggering condition is met. There are "If ..." optional Trigger effects (at least there's no other name for them) which can't miss the timing because of that "If" (instead of the usual "When"), but since Lightpulsar does have the "When", it's a regular optional Trigger with the timing problem.